# Split a 4-sheets-per-page PDF into a 1-sheets-per-page PDF

Tags: pdf

i'm looking for an automated way for splitting PDF files with 4 sheets per page into files with only 1 sheet per page.
the pages are arranged in 2x2.

Comment: Welcome to SO :-) This is about programming questions, not for looking for a cup of tea or advice or similar. We usually expect that you try something yourself, don't get completely the expected result, post everything here.

Comment: The very least one expects is that the question contains information for which programming language / environment a solution is sought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to [Chapter 6 of the "iText 7: Jump-start tutorial"](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/chapter-6-reusing-existing-pdf-documents) and scroll down to where it says **Tiling PDF pages**.

In that tutorial, we take this PDF:

[image]

And we tile it, so that the single page is distributed over four pages:

[image]

If `src` is the path to the original PDF, and `dest` is the path to the new PDF that you want to create, then you need this code:

```
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
PdfDocument sourcePdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(src));
PdfPage origPage = sourcePdf.getPage(1);
PdfFormXObject pageCopy = origPage.copyAsFormXObject(pdf);
Rectangle orig = origPage.getPageSize();
//Tile size
Rectangle tileSize = PageSize.A4.rotate();
AffineTransform transformationMatrix = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(
    tileSize.getWidth() / orig.getWidth() * 2f,
    tileSize.getHeight() / orig.getHeight() * 2f);
//The first tile
PdfPage page = pdf.addNewPage(PageSize.A4.rotate());
PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
canvas.concatMatrix(transformationMatrix);
canvas.addXObject(pageCopy, 0, -orig.getHeight() / 2f);
//The second tile
page = pdf.addNewPage(PageSize.A4.rotate());
canvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
canvas.concatMatrix(transformationMatrix);
canvas.addXObject(pageCopy, -orig.getWidth() / 2f, -orig.getHeight() / 2f);
//The third tile
page = pdf.addNewPage(PageSize.A4.rotate());
canvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
canvas.concatMatrix(transformationMatrix);
canvas.addXObject(pageCopy, 0, 0);
//The fourth tile
page = pdf.addNewPage(PageSize.A4.rotate());
canvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
canvas.concatMatrix(transformationMatrix);
canvas.addXObject(pageCopy, -orig.getWidth() / 2f, 0);
// closing the documents
pdf.close();
sourcePdf.close();
```

For the full example, see [TheGoldenGateBridge_Tiles.java](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/examples/chapter-6#1783-c06e02_thegoldengatebridge_tiles.java)

This example assumes that you understand how to compile and execute Java code. If you don't know Java, but you know C#, you can easily convert this Java code to C# code and use *iText 7 for C#* instead of *iText 7 for Java*.

If you don't know any of these programming languages, you should update your question and explain which language you want to use.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know Java good enough to build and compile it :) I just never really worked with PDF's, so i hadn't any clue about editing them.